# AJAX JSON load jQuery dataTable

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I have this php script in a file named qnams.php that returns JSON:

```
include ("../include/database.php");

include ("../include/sessions.php");

$select = "SELECT  column1,column2,column3,column4
           FROM  qnamtable WHERE  USER = '$username'";

$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select) or die(mysqli_error());

$out = array();

while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
    $out[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($out);

mysqli_free_result($query);
```

I found different posts on how to add the JSON directly into the dataTable, but was a little confused on how to proceed.

On my main page, I have this function at the bottom of the page:

```
$(function() {
    $('#example1').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "sScrollY": "auto",
        "sScrollCollapse": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true
    });
});
```

What do I need to add to this function to include the JSON with all the headers and data?

Comment: So...it would help if you have the most recent version of Jquery DataTables.  Acquiring a newer version helped solved a lot of the problems I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the other answers here were helpful, however in the end, I merely needed to acquire a recent version of jQuery DataTables.  I was using newer code with an older template and that was a main issue affecting my results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ajax option of Jquery Datatables

ajax : {
    url: 'the/path/to/php/file/with/jsondata'
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below,

```
$(function() {
    $('#example1').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "qnams.php" //set your php file location
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "sScrollY": "auto",
        "sScrollCollapse": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true
    });
});
```

The html should be like below, Make sure the **id** should be ***example1***

Set all the **headers** as below easily.

```
<table id="example1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column1</th>
      <th>column2</th>
      <th>column3</th>
      <th>column4</th>
      <th>column5</th>
      <th>column6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>column1</th>
      <th>column2</th>
      <th>column3</th>
      <th>column4</th>
      <th>column5</th>
      <th>column6</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Check more information from [here](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: but now how do I go about setting the column headers and adding the table cells with the data?

Comment: But I still do not see how to get the JSON values to populate in the table.  What am I missing?

Comment: @HoodCoderMan did you try my code?..When the `JSON` returns values in order the table will **automatically** gets populated.

Answer (score 1):

First I would say you should use `fetch_assoc`, not `fetch_array()`. `fetch_array()` will include both the associated *and* the indexed array :

```
[{"0":"x","column1":"x","1":"y","column2":"y"}]
```

we just need

```
[{"column1":"x","column2":"y"}]
```

Then here is a fully automated script for populating a

```
<table id="example1"></table>
```

with any JSON as long as it is wellformed (as your PHP script seems to do) :

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'qnams.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(json) {
        //build the column definitions for titles and data-indexes 
        var columns = [];
        Object.keys(json[0]).forEach(function(column) {
            columns.push({ title: column, data: column })
        })
        $('#example1').dataTable({      
            data : json,
            columns : columns,

            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "sScrollY": "auto",
            "sScrollCollapse": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true
        })
    }
});
```

I assume you are using 1.10.x of dataTatables.

Comment: Both your response and jlocker's below look promising, but I just cannot get either to work.  I will continue to test both answers until I am able to get it to work.  Thanks.

Comment: @HoodCoderMan, what does not work - are there any errors in the console? As long as you use `fetch_assoc` i hardly see what could go wrong :) try to console out `json' in the successhandler - do you ever reach it? Perhaps you have some blanks or other garbage in the response.

Comment: I am using fetch_assoc.  I inadvertently approved an edit by jlocker and it changed to fetch_array.  And the console shows no errors.  I am still testing.  I will get back to you.